# Regular expression to replace 2023-02-06T07:43:51.9732381Z with blanks

Tags: regex

I have a date stamp at the beginning of my log files, in the format `2023-02-06T07:43:51.9732381Z`

There are other various dates, I have tried to use notepad ++ to write a regular expression to replace all the data formats with just blanks. I would like to have a regular expression to replace the dates.

Secondly, what if I wanted the dates to be in the format `2023-02-06T07:43:51` ?

Comment: Can you show us the regex you've come up with so far?

Comment: try using \d to match digits

Comment: Try `^[TZ0-9\-.:]+` replace with space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the leading date on every line do this:

- Find what: `^2023[^ ]*`  (with trailing space)
- Replace with: (empty string)
- check the "Regular expression" radio button

To remove just the fractional seconds on every line do this:

- Find what: `^(2023[^\.]*)[^ ]*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- check the "Regular expression" radio button

Answer (score 0):

[The manual indicates](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions)
that Notepad++ uses "Boost" for regular expressions with its [search syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) and [replacement syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html).

So:

```
2023-02-06T07:43:51.9732381Z
```

could be matched at the start of lines by:

```
^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d[.]\d{7}Z
```

or more loosely by:

```
^\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+[.]\d+Z
```

To retain the part before the period, "mark" the sub-expression you want to keep:

```
^(\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+)[.]\d+Z
```

and refer to it in the replacement:

```
$1
```